# Python regular expression in a column of a dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have written a python script for Excel automation. I am stuck in between a point during this automation. I want to apply regular Expression in a column of a dataframe. Tried many ways but not able to produce exactly desired result as I wants. I have dataframe like following(short sample example) -

[image: this is input]

This is sample dataframe and this has large number of columns. I want to apply regular expression in column C named as ID column. I want to split data in this dataframe based upon $, & separator but also wants to ignore(delete) all the values between * and & or * and $. Row where we find empty cell in column C(ID) can be deleted or ignore. Following is example of output dataframe that I want-

[image: this is output]

I am have tried following-

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.read_excel("Deal Id Part Comparison Master File.xlsx", "Data Dump", header=1)
splits= []
for i in df['ID']:
    s = str(i)
    splits.append(re.split('\$|\&',s))

print(f' final list {splits}')
```

Above code is able to split data based upon $ and & and storing them in list. But data between * and $ or * and & is not ignored. Also I want to explode the data.

I am sure that there can be one liner to achieve this task but not able to generate final output

Comment: @Ch3steR but I want to ignore data between * and & or * or $. This will not give exact solution. Hence this will not give exact result

Comment: My bad missed that point. Added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Order': ['10-112','10-115'], 'Owner':['shubhman', 'rishab'], 'ID':['89ab$cd&78','']})

df['ID'] = df['ID'].str.replace(r'\*[^&$]*[&$]', '').str.split(r'[$&]') # Remove substrings between * and $ or &
df = df.explode('ID') # Split the rows with multiple IDs into multiple rows
df = df[df['ID'].astype(bool)] # Discard the rows with an empty ID
>>> df
    Order     Owner    ID
0  10-112  shubhman  89ab
0  10-112  shubhman    cd
0  10-112  shubhman    78
```

The regexps here match:

- `.replace(r'\*[^&$]*[&$]', '')` - replaces all substrings between `*` (matched with `\*`) and the closest, leftmost `&` or `$` (what comes first), see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OIl5i2/1)
- `.str.split(r'[$&]')` - splits with either `$` or `&` char (note you do not need to escape either inside a character class).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew thank you for your answer. this works good for me...

Comment: @Ch3steR thanks for your help also. As you have also tried your best to provide solution

Answer (score 0):

I would need to know more about the data to be safe but you should think in terms of vectors first and loops second when dealing with DataFrames.

Look into string accessor methods.

`pandas.Series.str.replace` to delete values between `*` and `$`, `&`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html

`pandas.Series.str.split`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html?highlight=str%20split#pandas.Series.str.split

`pandas.wide_to_long`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas.wide_to_long

`pandas.melt`

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html#pandas.melt